# How to show all functions in a javascript file?

Tags: javascript, js2-mode

How to show all functions in a js file? I am using js2, but any solution will do.

Additional info:
I am expecting an occur style buffer. This can persist and be edited if necessary. Or searched. This is preferable in my opinion to a helm style navigation tool for two reasons: 1. Helm is useful for navigating quickly to a known entity, but not for grokking structure. 2. I can continue investigation and keep that buffer alive as alluded to above.

What have I tried? I tried using a straight up occur, but the regex started to get too complex, and I imagine there is a better solution. I also know that js2 or something can parse js properly, and surely that would do something close to what I need, and properly too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`js-mode` supports the minor mode `semantic-mode`. You can activate it with <kbd>M-x</kbd> `semantic-mode`.
<kbd>M-x</kbd> `imenu-add-to-menubar` <kbd>RET</kbd> `Index` <kbd>RET</kbd> adds a menu item "Index" to the menu bar with submenus `Functions` and `Variables`.
You can activate semantic mode by default with the following lines in your init file:

```el
(defun js-setup-semantic ()
  "Setup semantic mode for js."
  (semantic-mode)
  (imenu-add-to-menubar "Index"))

(add-hook 'js-mode-hook 'js-setup-semantic)
```

If you want to have the functions listed in a buffer you can use [`imenu-tree`](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/imenu-tree.el).

Alternatively, there is [imenu-list](https://github.com/bmag/imenu-list) available on melpa. You can install it with <kbd>M-x</kbd> `package-install` <kbd>RET</kbd> `imenu-list` <kbd>RET</kbd> if you have `package-archives` configured for `melpa`.

---

## Variant: Imenu in an Occur buffer

I've put together a small package [`imenu-occur.el`](https://github.com/TobiasZawada/occur-imenu) that shows the Imenu in an [Occur buffer](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Other-Repeating-Search.html#index-Occur-mode-1058).

In JavaScript files it shows the analysis result of [Semantic](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Semantic.html). That result is not very complete for JavaScript files but maybe useful for you.

You can install that package by putting [`imenu-occur.el`](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/TobiasZawada/occur-imenu/master/occur-imenu.el) into your load path and adding
`(autoload 'occur-imenu "occur-imenu")`
to your init file.

You can try it by going to your JavaScript buffer and calling <kbd>M-x</kbd> `occur-imenu` <kbd>RET</kbd>.

Comment: This doesn't seem to give me what I expected. I was expecting something like an occur buffer with the lines containing all function and classes

Comment: @cammil I added `imenu-tree` to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you're looking for `speedbar` which will open a side-window which lists the same functions as `imenu-add-to-menubar` but inside a buffer.

Comment: Hi Stefan. "Maybe you're looking for speedbar...": No he isn't. He is expecting an occur buffer since he wants to use the special properties of such a buffer. One of those properties is the possibility to edit the occurrences within the occur buffer. He has clarified that in his last edit of the question.